# Differential of $Hom$ complexes

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, graded-modules

I'm a bit confused about **Example 22.26.6** from [Stacks project on Hom complexes](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09L9). Let $R$ a ring and $A^{\bullet}, B^{\bullet}$ two complexes of $R$-modules. Then we can define the Hom complex $\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits ^ {\bullet}(A^\bullet , B^\bullet ) $ as

$$\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits ^ n(A^\bullet , B^\bullet ) = \prod \nolimits _{p + q = n} \mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits _\mathcal {B}(A^{-q}, B^ p)$$

end endow it with a differential as follows. Let $f \in \mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits ^ n(A^\bullet , B^\bullet )$. Then

$$\text{d}(f) = \text{d}_ B \circ f - (-1)^ n f \circ \text{d}_ A$$

In terms of components, if $f=(f_{p,q})$ with $f_{p, q} : A^{-q} \to B^ p$ we have

$$\begin{equation}  \label{dga-equation-differential-hom-complex} \text{d}(f_{p, q}) = \text{d}_ B \circ f_{p, q} - (-1)^{p + q} f_{p, q} \circ \text{d}_ A \end{equation}$$

Note that the first term of this expression is in $\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits _\mathcal {B}(A^{-q}, B^{p + 1})$ and the second term is in $\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits _\mathcal {B}(A^{-q - 1}, B^ p)$.

Then it is claimed in (2) that

an element $f$ in $\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}\nolimits ^ n(A^\bullet , B^\bullet )$ has $d(f)=0$ if and only if the morphism $f : A^\bullet \to B^\bullet [n]$ of graded objects in the category of complexes over $A$ is actually a  [map of complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex#Chain_maps).

I'm not sure why this is true. Let $f=(f_{p,q}):A^\bullet \to B^\bullet [n]$. Then $f_{p,q}: A^{-q} \to B^{-q}[n]= B^{n-q}$ with $p=n-q$ and since it is a map of complexes we have $d_B \circ f_{p-1, q+1} = f_{p,q} \circ d_A$.

Assume $n$ is odd. Then $-(-1)^n=1$
and $-(-1)^{(p) + (q)} f_{p,q} \circ d_A$ cannot "neutralize" $d_B \circ f_{p-1, q+1}$. Thus $d(f) \neq 0$, I think. This contradicts the claim (2) or do I misunderstand the issue?

Comment: Be careful with the shift, a lot of shifts actually multiply the differential in some degrees by -1, which you need to do in order to get a nice tensor hom adjunction, and that [1] is actually a tensor product with the shifted tensor unit.

Comment: @Enkidu: oooh yes, of course, the differential of $B^\bullet [n]$ is not only shifted but is also multiplied by $(-1)^n$ https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0119 Thank you!